# Can I show the scrollbar on iPad even when I'm not scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, ios

I'm using "-webkit-overflow-scrolling": "touch" to show the scrollbar on a scrollable  element on iPad.
The scroll button appears only when i'm touching the screen but I would like to be permanently visible so the user can see that there is more content.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function available to make scrollbar permanently visible. But if you want to implement some thing like this, you should customize this using delegate function for UIScrollView. 
Doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html